# Racket - produce base to the exponent without multiplying

Tags: racket

I am trying to finish a question which asks me to write a function such that it consumes two natural numbers base and expt, and produces base to the expt. However, the only built-in arithmetic functions allowed are the functions add1 and sub1. 
How can I achieve this using recursion and helper functions?

Example:

```
(check-expect (exponent-without-mult 3 3) 27)
```

Comment: Well, you can construct your own multiplication function first by using your own addition, which in turn can be constructed by using `add1` and `sub1`.

Answer (score 0):

Addition is repeated "add 1":

```
(define (nat+ nat1 nat2)
  (cond
    [(zero? nat1) nat2]
    [(positive? nat1) (add1 (nat+ (sub1 nat1) nat2))]))
```

Multiplication is repeated addition:

```
(define (nat* nat1 nat2)
  (cond
    [(zero? nat1) 0]
    [(positive? nat1) (nat+ (nat* (sub1 nat1) nat2) nat2)]))
```

Exponentiation is repeated multiplication:

```
(define (nat^ nat1 nat2)
  (cond
    [(zero? nat2) 1]
    [(positive? nat1) (nat* nat1 (nat^ nat1 (sub1 nat2)))]))
```